# how to read CSV file data using importcsv plugin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, yii, yii-extensions

i want to read data from CSV file ( which is stored in my web directory ) using YII y  , after searching i came across [importcsv extension](https://github.com/Ardem/yii-importcsv-extension).

i  have tried setting modules and path , but now i don't know how to use this `importcsv` extension , i didn't get any example over net too , just to read data from CSV and then store it in mysql database.

here is my config.php

```
 'importcsv'=>array(
            'path'=>'assets/importCsv/', // path to folder for saving csv file and file with import params
        ),
```

Comment: did you try to access http://host/yourproject/importcsv.

Or here:

http://host/yourproject/index.php?r=importcsv.

Comment: ya tried and its showing a blank page

Answer (score 0):

1. in your yii application -> in **protected** folder you need to create **modules** folder;
2. create **importcsv** folder in **modules** folder;
3. extract the github extension code ("yii-importcsv-extension-master->importcsv") in importcsv root folder (is important to have the same name of the folder with the name of the module set in config). You need to have one folder named **importcsv** in modules folder containing all the code ("views folder, controller folder, models folder...etc.");
4. in **config->main.php** you need to set in **modules**

   `'importcsv'=>array(
               'path'=>'assets/importCsv/', // path to folder for saving csv file and file with import params
           ),`

**Very important** !!! The module need to be extracted in **protected/modules** folder not in **protected/extensions** folder and the name writhed in config/main.php -> modules need to be exactly the same on the folder extracted in modules.

1. Access the module with the same name writhed in config:

   http://www.host.com/yourproject/importcsv.

   Or here:

   http://www.host.com/yourproject/index.php?r=importcsv.